# date difference between many dates for many devices that stop and start (worktime)

Tags: sql-server, datediff

I have a table like so:

```
        date        | machine | activity_type | Status
31.12.2018 23:15:00 | device2 |     type2     | Start
1.1.2019   00:05:00 | device1 |     type1     | Start
1.1.2019   00:10:00 | device2 |     type2     |  Stop
1.1.2019   00:15:00 | device2 |     type1     | Start
1.1.2019   00:20:00 | device1 |     type1     |  Stop
1.1.2019   00:25:00 | device1 |     type3     | Start
2.1.2019   00:23:00 | device1 |     type3     |  Stop
3.1.2019   00:00:00 | device2 |     type1     |  Stop
```

My desired output (for day 1.1.2019) would be:

```
date              | Duration | Activity_type | Machine
1.1.2019 00:05:00 | 00:15:00 |    type1      | device1
1.1.2019 00:00:00 | 00:10:00 |    type2      | device2
1.1.2019 00:15:00 | 23:45:00 |    type1      | device2
1.1.2019 00:25:00 | 23:35:00 |    type3      | device1
```

So that:

Device1 starts at 00:05:00 and stops at 00:20:00 so duration is 00:15:00.

Device2 stops (it's work started f.e. day earlier) at 00:10:00 so duration is 00:10:00.

Device2 starts 00:15:00 and doesn't stop working on this day so duration is 23:45:00.

Device1 starts at 00:25:00 and also doesn't stop working on this day so duration is 23:35:00

I Came up with this but it keeps showing NULL

```
SELECT
w1.Machine,
w1.Date,
w1.Type,
DateDiff(SECOND,[prevdate],[Date]) AS Duration
FROM
(
    SELECT
        Maszyna,
        Typ,
        Date,
        (
            SELECT Max(Date)
            FROM WorkHours as T2
            WHERE
                T2.Machine=T1.Machine
            AND T2.Type=T1.Type
            AND T2.Date < T1.Date
        ) AS prevdate
    FROM WorkHours AS T1
    ) as w1;
```

Comment: If you don't know where to start, at least show us what reserach you've performed and what you didn't understand. You've tagged `DATEDIFF` here, so it seems you want to do something with that. What didn't you understand about the `DATEDIFF` function?

Comment: @Larnu I updated the thread and showed my approach, however it doesn't work :/

Comment: It not working isn't an issue, that's why you're asking the question (if it did work you wouldn't be). Showing your attempt is what really helps us.

Comment: Are you passing the desired **date value(01-01-2019)** as a parameter?

Comment: Are sure about row 2 `1.1.2019 00:00:00 | 00:10:00 |    type2      | device2` - it's probably `type1`, `device2`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, you join your table to itself and use a window function to return the next corresponding stop event for each start event

The query returns all events that started on 1st Jan and their respective stop events (the stop event has the same Machine and Activity Type)

NB - I think the 2nd row in your expect output is erroneous as there is no stop event for device 2, type 2 (it also looks like it has a typo - should `1.1.2019 00:00:00` be `1.1.2019 00:10:00`?)

```
CREATE TABLE StartTimes
(
    [Date]          DATETIME,
    Machine         VARCHAR(7),
    Activity_Type   VARCHAR(5),
    [Status]        VARCHAR(5)
)

INSERT INTO StartTimes VALUES

('12/31/2018 23:15:00','device2','type2','Start'),
('1/1/2019   00:05:00','device1','type1','Start'),
('1/1/2019   00:10:00','device2','type2','Stop'),
('1/1/2019   00:15:00','device2','type1','Start'),
('1/1/2019   00:20:00','device1','type1','Stop'),
('1/1/2019   00:25:00','device1','type3','Start'),
('1/2/2019   00:23:00','device1','type3','Stop'),
('1/3/2019   00:00:00','device2','type1','Stop')

SELECT  StartDate,
        EndDate,
        CONVERT(varchar(12), DATEADD(MINUTE,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,StartDate,EndDate),0),114) AS Duration,
        Activity_Type,
        Machine
FROM    (
          SELECT    s.[Date] AS StartDate,
                    s.Machine,
                    s.Activity_Type,
                    s.[Status],
                    s1.[Date] AS EndDate,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.date ORDER BY s1.Date) as RowN
          FROM      StartTimes s
                    JOIN StartTimes s1
                        ON s.[Date] < s1.[Date] AND
                           s.Machine = s1.Machine AND
                           s.Activity_Type = s1.Activity_Type AND
                           s.Status = 'Start' AND
                           s1.Status = 'Stop'
       ) a
WHERE  RowN= 1 AND
       [StartDate] >= '2019-01-01' AND
       [StartDate]  < '2019-01-02'
ORDER BY StartDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I have done the `T-SQL` for your case.

**Schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE Your_Table(date DATETIME,machine VARCHAR(100),activity_type VARCHAR(100), Status VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO Your_Table VALUES('2018-12-31 23:15:00','device2','type2','Start')
INSERT INTO Your_Table VALUES('2019-01-01 00:05:00','device1','type1','Start')
INSERT INTO Your_Table VALUES('2019-01-01 00:10:00','device2','type2','Stop')
INSERT INTO Your_Table VALUES('2019-01-01 00:15:00','device2','type1','Start')
INSERT INTO Your_Table VALUES('2019-01-01 00:20:00','device1','type1','Stop')
INSERT INTO Your_Table VALUES('2019-01-01 00:25:00','device1','type3','Start')
INSERT INTO Your_Table VALUES('2019-01-02 00:23:00','device1','type3','Stop')
INSERT INTO Your_Table VALUES('2019-01-03 00:00:00','device2','type1','Stop')
INSERT INTO Your_Table VALUES('2019-01-03 00:05:00','device2','type2','Start')
INSERT INTO Your_Table VALUES('2019-01-03 00:25:00','device2','type2','Stop')
```

And I'm passing the `date value` in variables and use them in the Query.

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME = '2019-01-01 00:00:00',@EndDate DATETIME = '2019-01-02 00:00:00'

SELECT MIN(date),
    CONVERT(varchar(12),DATEADD(minute,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,CASE WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN Status = 'Start' THEN date END)<@Date THEN @Date ELSE MAX(CASE WHEN Status = 'Start' THEN date END) END,
             CASE WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN Status = 'Stop' THEN date END)>@EndDate THEN @EndDate ELSE MAX(CASE WHEN Status = 'Stop' THEN date END) END),0), 114)
             ,Activity_type
             ,Machine
FROM(
    SELECT *,
       ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY machine,activity_type ORDER BY date))+1)/2 RN 
    FROM Your_Table
    )A
GROUP BY Activity_type,Machine,RN
```

You can check the output in the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/28044/2)